# How I can to access return value of jQuery File Uploader - Upload File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image

Which below option can I use to return the upload JSON class value?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
                url: "Gallery/Upload", // Server URL which handles File uploads
                method: "POST", // Upload Form method type POST or GET.
                enctype: "multipart/form-data", // Upload Form enctype.
                formData: null, // An object that should be send with file upload. data: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
                returnType: null,
                allowedTypes: "*", // List of comma separated file extensions: Default is "*". Example: "jpg,png,gif"
                fileName: "file", // Name of the file input field. Default is file
                formData: {},
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: show us which plugin you have used?

Comment: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: see these all callback methods https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options , you can use `fileuploaddone` callback

Comment: thanks very much from   Girish  @ Girish